# In Photoshop, are the corner handles of a selected object independently controllable with the keyboard?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If you make a selection with the rectangular marquee tool, and then attempt to transform using ***`Edit > Transform > Distort`*** it creates a bounding box with handles around the selection, for you to manipulate using the mouse.

But is it possible, say, to select the bottom right handle with some kind of keyboard command? And then move it using ***up/left/down/right***?

Comment: You can edit the bounding box by going Select->Transform Selection. Hold down CTRL and click one corner selection point and you can manipulate that point individually. As far as I know you can't do this by units or precise increments as keyboard nudges would offer. If you want to precisely construct shapes then maybe start in Illustrator and import shapes as smart objects to PS, which you again can convert to selection paths.

Comment: You asked about the distort tool not the regular bounding box, sorry. But it appears to be very similar options available for distort as well.